# Sens de "la Charte" ici?

Tags: sens

Je viens de trouver un commentaire sur un article qui contient le mot "Charte":

> Tiens censuré pour avoir demandé un article des Décodeurs sur les réactions des figures et mouvements féministes en France et en Europe par rapport aux dissimulations des agressions sexuelles de Suède et d'Allemagne et concernant les agressions elles-mêmes. Rien de plus mais la Charte a dû éclater en sanglots devant une telle exigence. Légitime non ?

Que veut dire "la Charte" ici, en anglais ?  La traduction semble d'être "charter" mail ça ne porte aucun sens.  Est-ce qu'il veut dire "the Chancellor", ie. "Chancellor Merkel" peut-être ?  Pourquoi pas "la Chancelière" ?

---

I just found a comment on an article that contains the word "Charte":

> Tiens censuré pour avoir demandé un article des Décodeurs sur les réactions des figures et mouvements féministes en France et en Europe par rapport aux dissimulations des agressions sexuelles de Suède et d'Allemagne et concernant les agressions elles-mêmes. Rien de plus mais la Charte a dû éclater en sanglots devant une telle exigence. Légitime non ?

What does "la Charte" mean here, in English?  The translation seems to be "charter" but that doesn't seem to make sense.  Does it mean "the Chancellor", ie. "Chancellor Merkel" perhaps?  Why not "la Chancelière"?

Comment: Non c'est *Le Monde* une publication francaise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La charte désigne ici un règlement. En l'occurence je pense qu'il s'agit ici des règles du journal "Le monde" (qui héberge un blog connu appelé les décodeurs).

En gros, il s'agit d'un internaute qui se plaint de s'être fait censurer.

Comment: Alors pourquoi est-ce qu'il dit que la Charte a "éclater en sanglots"?  C'est pas une personne...?

Comment: Difficile d'exprimer ça ^^ On désigne ici une personne (un modérateur), mais d'après l'application d'un objet (le règlement). C'est une façon un peu humoristique de s'exprimer, qui n'est pas tout à fait juste si l'on suit à la lettre les règles du Français, mais qui est courrament utilisé quand on cherche à donner un ton ironique.

Comment: @Jez en effet, ce doit être une figure de style, une "personnification", qui consiste à donner vie à un objet (ou une idée), et lui donner des sentiments. Ici, on souligne donc que si la charte était une personne, elle serait elle même outrée par ce qu'a fait le modérateur au nom de la charte.

Answer (score 1):

*Il n'y a pas assez de contexte, pour pouvoir s'avancer dans une hypothèse correcte, il nous faudrait plus d'explication sur l'idée principale de cette article.*

Je suppose que ton texte, fait référence au mouvement féminisme qui commence à apparaitre au 19ème siècle. A cette époque des [Chartes constitutionnelles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charte_constitutionnelle_du_4_juin_1814) ont été successivement mises en place pour le gouvernement provisoire.

Si on se rattache à la situation donnée la majuscule à "*Charte*" confirme l'idée d'un document important.

> a dû éclater en sanglots

Il s'agit d'une [personnification](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/figures-de-style/personnification.php), *est une figure qui confère à des entités abstraites, à des animaux ou à des inanimés (c’est-à-dire des choses) des traits de comportement, de sentiment ou de pensée propres aux êtres humains.*